# Reactjs: Changing props outside the main scope

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made a test where I do `React.render()` in a child component and pass a prop to it. The app structure looks like:

```
<App>
  <Child />
</App>
```

Then in `<Child />`, I render `<Outside />` component with another `React.render()`. When I checked in Chrome React firebug, the App structure is:

```
<App>
  <Child />
</App>
<Outside />
```

instead of:

```
<App>
  <Child />
    <Outside />
</App>
```

However, when passing a `{selected : true }` state from `<App />`, it displays well as a prop in `<Outside />`, but when I make a state change to `{ selected : false }` in `<App />`, both `<Child />` and `<Outside />` don't receive the updated prop. I think it happens because `<Outside />` is out of the `<App />` scope so the data flow doesn't flow well. (Sorry for my English)

You can check the test here: http://jsbin.com/yazaqo/1/edit?js,console,output

What I'm trying to ask is: Is there any other way to update a component which is *outside* the App scope?

Comment: Why don't you pass the new value to the code that calls `render` on `Outside`?  You'll need to trigger a rerender of the second tree.

Comment: @WiredPrairie React.render(<Outside selected={ this.props.selected } toggle={ this.props.toggle } />, div); How do I suppose to pass the new value? It's the selected={ this.props.selected } that passes it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Child` component is receiving the updated prop, its just not being logged to the console.

Only `render` and `componentWillReceiveProps` are invoked when a component receives new props, so if you move the `console.log` to either one of those methods, you'll see the updated value.

This is also why `Outside` is not receiving the updated prop.  You're rendering it in `componentDidMount`, which is only invoked once, when the component is mounted.

It should be rendered in `Child`'s `render` method the same way `Child` is rendered in the `App` component.  The other option would be to render it in `componentWillReceiveProps`, although you may run into some problems doing it that way.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, thank you mate, you inspire me. I have tried it too with `componentDidUpdate()` and the changed prop is detected. But actually, the reason I have to render `<Outside />` outside the `<Child />` render method is I want to wrap it with some HTML DOM (in this case "div") to be able to pass it to a method that accepts HTML as its argument, like GoogleMap's `infowindow.setContent()`. Do you have any idea how to handle such this circumtance? Btw, I want to really upvote your answer but my reputation tells everything